# Behat and Symfony2 bundle issue?

Tags: php, symfony, behat

I've got some problems with Behat (2.4.*@dev) init process inside Symfony2 bundle (ver 2.2.2). After command:

```
bin/behat --init "@CompanyAppBundle"
```

behat directories are created inside application root directory, not in bundle. The output is:

```
+d features - place your *.feature files here
+d features/bootstrap - place bootstrap scripts and static files here
+f features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php - place your feature related code here
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Problem solved. I put behat.yml in app/config/ directory, so bin/behat can't find it.

Comment: You could keep the `behat.yml` file in the `app/config` directory if you wanted to. `--config` option to the rescue! http://docs.behat.org/guides/6.cli.html#initialization-options

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about Behat v2.4, but for Behat v3.0, add the bundle to the 'suites' directive of behat.yml:

```
# behat.yml
default:
  suites:
    company_app_suite:
      type: symfony_bundle
      bundle: CompanyAppBundle
  extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
```

Comment: I'd tried that one and the Features folder was added to the bundle. But when Im running the suite, it cannot find the FeatureContext. can you show me the directory structure and how to setup further?

Comment: My directory structure is:
/features/bootstrap/{project_name}/Bundle/{bundle}Bundle/Features/Context/FeatureContext.php

where {project_name}/Bundle/{bundle}Bundle is the same structure as under the src directory.

Comment: I see. I thought they should live inside the src/ folder. Btw are you familiar with Domain Drive Design? Because Im wondering where should I put the test for my Domain Models

Answer (score 0):

Either Behat can't find your configuration, try specifying it like so:

```sh
bin/behat -c alternative/location/to/behat.yml --init "@CompanyAppBundle"
```

Or you haven't enabled the Symfony2Extension in your (default) configuration, try specifying it like so:

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
```